# Объединить 2 датафрейма в один

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

У меня имеется два датафрейма:

```
df1
Day Study
1     1
3     2
4     1
5     4
6     1
7     1
8     2
9     1
10    1
11    1
12    1
13    1
14    1
15    1
16    1
17    1
18    1
19    1
20    1
21    1
22    1


df2
Day
0     1
1     2
2     3
3     4
4     5
5     6
6     7
.......
30   31
```

df - это какого числа сколько исследований было сделано. df2 - числа месяца. В данном случае их 31. Как теперь объединить их, чтобы количество исследований встало на нужные даты, а в те дни, когда исследование не проводилось, ставился 0?

Пример

```
Day Amount

1    1
2    0  (т.к. 2 числа исслед.не было)
3    2
и т.д.
```

Comment: Покажите ваш код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем их объединять, если вы все можете сделать с одним датафреймом?

```
df1["Day"] = df1["Day"].astype("int")
df1.set_index("Day").reindex(range(1, 32)).fillna(0)
```

```
     Study
Day       
1      1.0
2      0.0
3      2.0
4      1.0
5      4.0
6      1.0
7      1.0
8      2.0
9      1.0
10     1.0
11     1.0
12     1.0
13     1.0
14     1.0
15     1.0
16     1.0
...
```